# Pseudo-quine polyglot language-detection counters

Tags: popularity-contest, quine, polyglot

Quines are fun. Polyglots are fun, too. Polyglot Quines exist, but we can raise the bar even higher.

Write a file that contains a valid program for languages α, β, and γ. When the file is executed (possibly after compiling it) as a language α or β program, the program's output shall be of the same form as a valid submission to this contest. If your file is executed as a language γ program, it shall output a number. The value of this number is the chain of previous executions of the program interpreted as a binary number.

This explanation might be a bit hard to understan, so here is an example. Let Α, Β, and Γ be functions that execute their input as a language α, β, or γ resp. program and return the output of these programs. Let *x* be a valid submission to this contest. Then the following expression, where we process *x* through language β, α, β, α, α, β, and γ in this order, shall yield 41, since 41<sub>10</sub> = 101001<sub>2</sub>.

> Γ(Β(Α(Α(Β(Α(Β(*x*)))))))

You may not assume that penultimate execution in the chain is an execution in language β. For the case where your original submission is directly executed as a language γ program, it shall print 0.

Your program shall behave correctly for up to sixteen compilations in the chain; that is, the highest number your program might print out at the end is 2<sup>15</sup> - 1. Of course, your program is allowed to support longer compilation chains.

This is a popularity contest to encourage creative solutions. The submission with the highest vote tally wins.

Comment: Can the three languages be equal (even though it would drastically reduce upvotes)?

Comment: @Zgarb I'd love to see a solution where some (or all) of the languages are equal. Let's see how you manage to distinguish equal languages.

Comment: ...I see. :D I read the challenge too hastily.

Comment: @Zgarb  how about  different   versions  of   the  same   language?   `magic += Number(System.env.lang_version[-1])`

Comment: @JanDvorak Possible, but unless it's really crafty I don't think you're going to get many upvotes. A bit boring.

Comment: Are we allowed to read source file or access external resources?

Comment: @randomra that would count as a standard loophole, I'm afraid.

Comment: @FUZxxl in the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king ;-)

Comment: +1 for using greek letters instead of the boring `a,b,c` or `1,2,3` =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Python 2, Python 3, ><> (Fish)

```python
#;n0
import sys
x='\\\'\nn#;n0import sysx=v=int(1/2*2)sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851])n'
v=int(1/2*2)
sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851])
```

### Python explanation

The Python 2 and Python 3 interpreters work similarly except the `v=int(1/2*2)` variable gets different values (`0` and `1`) as Python 2 uses float division and Python 3 uses integer division.

In every run they add the expression `+0*2` or `+1*2`  to the first line (after `#;n`) and to the `x` string (after the last write command). The ><> interpreter uses the first addition and the Pythons use the second one to create correct quines.

Code after `B(A(B(B(x))))`:

```python
#;n+1*2+0*2+1*2+1*20
import sys
x='\\\'\nn#;n0import sysx=v=int(1/2*2)sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851])+1*2+0*2+1*2+1*2n'
v=int(1/2*2)
sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[0:1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[4:7]),sys.stdout.write(x[7:8]),sys.stdout.write(x[8:18]),sys.stdout.write(x[18:20]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851]),sys.stdout.write(chr(43)+str(v)+chr(42)+chr(50)),sys.stdout.write(x[851:-1]),sys.stdout.write(x[3:4]),sys.stdout.write(x[1:2]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[20:32]),sys.stdout.write(x[2:3]),sys.stdout.write(x[32:851])
```

### ><> (Fish) explanation

When you run the ><> interpreter the code pointer bounces back from the `#` wraps around the first line and starting from the end of the first line and heading West starts pushing numbers onto the stack. If an operator comes (`+` or `*`) it pops the top two elements from the stack and pushes back the result. With this method we end up with the base2 representation of the previous runs (`13` in the former example). This is the desired number so we output it with `n` and terminate with `;`.

Comment: This is pretty nice.